# NgxPermissions hasPermission check inside an Observable method in Angular 6

Tags: angular, observable

I am using [ngx-permissions](https://github.com/AlexKhymenko/ngx-permissions) to handle the permissions in my Angular 6 application.  I would like to check the permissions of the user before retrieving data from an endpoint.  Ngx-permissions provides a way to check the user's permission in the method hasPermission(permissionName).  This returns a promise.  I would like to retrieve the data from the endpoint using an Observable as I have read this is the Angular way to do things.  However I'm not sure how to combine the Promise from the permission check and the Observable method.

Service:

```
getData(): Observable<Item[]<>>{
  this.permissionsService.hasPermission(Permission.CanViewData)
  .then(hasPermission => {
    if (hasPermission) {
      return this.http.get<Item[]>('http://endpoint/getdata', httpOptions).pipe(
        map(this.extractData), // this is calculated too late
        catchError(e => this.handleError(e, 'GetData', new Observable<Item[]>()))
      );
    }
  });
  return new Observable<Item[]>(); // this is always passed to the component
}
```

Component:

```
getData(): void {
  this.service.getData().subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data
  });
}
```

I realise I'm not calling the hasPermission method correctly as my code always falls through to the final `return new Observable<Item[]>();`.  However the data is being retrieved from my endpoint - if I add a console.log I can see the result of `map(this.extractData)`.  It just is calculated too late.  The component has already moved on and is using the empty `Item[]`.

How can I use the permissionsService.hasPermission from ngx-permissions to check the permission of the user before attempting to retrieve the data and still return an Observable to my component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, and for the record it is more general rxjs question. Anyway you have to convert the promise to observable and then chain the invocation like this:

```
import { of, from, Observable } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map, filter, flatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

class Caller {

  public constructor(){}

  public call() : Observable<Item[]> {
    //the promise returned from your method it has to be typed with boolean
    var permission = new Promise<boolean>(function(resolve, reject) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        resolve(true);
      }, 300);
    });


    //calling from(prommisse) converts promes to observable.\
    return from(permission)
    .pipe(
      filter(t => t), //just a trick to avoid if statemt in the flatMap call
      flatMap( t => {
        //call your http get method here
        var it:Item = {property: "1"};
        return of<Item[]>([it])
      }))

  }
}

export class Item {
  property: String
}
```